# Save only changes without Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple edit form for my dataset and I want to know if it is possible to only save the textboxes.. and so on.. there I realy changed.

I don't use the EF for my MVC application and now I hope it was not the wrong decision.

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Product Informations</legend>

    <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Id, "Product Id")</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</div>

    <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Name, "Product Name")</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</div>

    <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductInformation.GeneralDescription, "General Description")</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.ProductInformation.GeneralDescription)</div>

    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />

</fieldset>
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your post doesn't say anything about how you are accessing your data, other that "not using" EF".  You need to use some sort of Data Access Framework; ADO, EF, NHibernate etc.  Since you are using MVC Entity Framework would be recommended.

Comment: Then you'll have to write your raw ado code/queries in your controller to write data to the database.  Here is a tutorial to look at coding ADO http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1155/Simple-ADO-NET-Database-Read-Insert-Update-and-Del

Comment: I know how to update data with ADO but this dont solve my problem to compare edit fields.. :-/

Comment: So if you want to conditionally update, in your controller on submit you will have to compare whats in the database with what was submitted and conditionally update fields based on what has changed.  Does that help?

Comment: @JamesSmith Yes, a flag is going to be needed in any case.  Even if he were using EF, there would ultimately be a decision as to whether or not to update the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the data access strategy has anything to do with whether or not one calls the "Update Method".  Let's say you *are* using EF.  Inside the controller, you would still have to transfer data between the model and the business object / entity and then decide whether or not to set `EntityState.Modified`.  If you're using a repository, you could use an updated flag.  Maybe this is in the controller or maybe you put the logic in the business entity and have it update itself.  For example, if you're using a repository / UofW and put the "updated" logic inside the controller, it might look like:

```
    using (UnitOfWork work = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        IProductFactory factory = work.ProductFactory;
        Product product = factory.GetByID(model.Id);
        product.Name = model.Name;

        // TO UPDATE OR NOT?  THAT IS THE QUESTION
        factory.Update(expected);
        work.Save();
    }
```

You need some kind of flag to help:

```
    using (UnitOfWork work = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        bool updated = true;
        IProductFactory factory = work.ProductFactory;
        Product product = factory.GetByID(model.Id);
        if(product.Name != model.Name)
        {
            product.Name = model.Name;
            updated = true;
        }

        // TO UPDATE OR NOT?  THAT IS THE QUESTION
        if(updated)
        {
          factory.Update(expected);
          work.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But in your case, it is mandatory to retrieve the actual data out of database. Isn't this overhead?
How did web developers handle this before ORM Frameworks are out?

Comment: The strategy you see above is simply a repository pattern and unit of work.  It is independent of the data access strategy.  In fact, the code above is from a test case implemented in both ADO.Net (using Dapper) and EF.  The test case code is identical in either strategy.  Retrieving the object, transferring properties and saving has always been a common strategy since forever.  The only other strategy would be to make an update method specific to the table fields of interest.  Then perhaps you can relegate the comparison to a stored procedure (crazy, in my opinion)

Comment: Hmm but what do you think is the better way.. Retrieve the current data of the DB and Company with the form and only Save differences or update allways all data..?

Comment: Personally, I would just always run the update and move on.  These are micro-optimizations and you likely have bigger fish to fry.